# aggregate on a sepcific month in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What i want to do is to take the number of (things) for each city for each month

I tried this:

## get the number of apartments in each city in each month

```
GET /bla bla/_search
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs": {
    "whateveryouwant": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "posting_date",
        "interval": "month",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "anything": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "city"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but the problem is that it is not for month, but for just the first day of each month.

any clue how to solve it please?

Comment: Please share the output

Answer (score 0):

Actually it will be showing first date of the month in `key_as_string`. But the document count is actually aggregation of the whole month.

E.g.

```
   "aggregations": {
      "month_histogram": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key_as_string": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
               "key": 1388534400000,
               "doc_count": 4276
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

You can validate count using below query and match the count with aggregation result.

```
POST blah blah/_count
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "posting_date": {
                           "gte": "2016-01-01",
                           "lte": "2016-01-31"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```